# Rename JKS alias with java programmatically

Tags: java, keystore, jks

I would like to know how can I rename an alias of a keystore, programmatically in java, not using keytool.

I have my `java.security.KeyStore` object, containing an certain alias. How can I rename it?

Comment: Why? What do you care what the alias is?

Comment: @EJP internal requisites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The KeyStore API does not provide a rename operation for aliases. But what you can do is:

1. Save the content (key pair, certificates) of the keystore entry that you want to rename.
2. Delete the entry.
3. Create a new entry with the saved content and the new alias.

As Java code:

```
Key privateKey = keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
Certificate[] certs = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
keyStore.setKeyEntry(newAlias, privateKey, password.toCharArray(), certs);
keyStore.deleteEntry(alias);
```

Of course this does not work if the private key is stored on a hardware device (smartcard or HSM) and therefore is not readable.

If the keystore entry contains a trusted certificate, the code looks a bit different:

```
Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry(newAlias, cert);
keyStore.deleteEntry(alias);
```

Comment: This doesn't work
`java.security.keystoreexception can only replace keys with same alias`

It's not possible to rename the alias for the Private key.

Comment: @PedroRomão With which Java version?

Comment: Android with Java 1.8